# Ping does not work in webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a ping method in both a console application and webapi application. Ping works the console app but not the webapi app. It always is timedout. Here is the code I am using:

```
namespace Ping.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PingController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.PingItem>> Post([FromBody]List<string> hosts)
        {
            List<Task<Models.PingItem>> tasks = new List<Task<Models.PingItem>>();

            foreach (var host in hosts)
            {
                tasks.Add(Ping(host));
            }

            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

            return results;
        }

        private async Task<Models.PingItem> Ping(string host)
        {
            Models.PingItem pi = new Models.PingItem();
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            var result = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(host, 50000);
            pi.Host = host;
            pi.Live = result.Status == IPStatus.Success ? true : false;
            pi.Time = result.RoundtripTime;
            return pi;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could this be a network - firewall related issue? For example pinging is blocked by default on Windows Azure VM's

Comment: Is the ping coming back timed out or the http request is timing out? Assuming you are talking about the HTTP request, does the timeout happen even if it’s a single host? AFAIK, the default request timeout limit for aspnet core apps is 2mins.

Comment: @MuqeetKhan The http request works. The ping does not work.